# Solr sorting by custom function query

Tags: java, solr

I'm running into some issues developing a custom function query using Solr 3.6.2.
My goal is to be able to implement a custom sorting technique.

I have a field called daily_prices_str, it is a single value str.

Example:

```
<str name="daily_prices_str">
2014-05-01:130 2014-05-02:130 2014-05-03:130 2014-05-04:130 2014-05-05:130 2014-05-06:130 2014-05-07:130 2014-05-08:130 2014-05-09:130 2014-05-10:130 2014-05-11:130 2014-05-12:130 2014-05-13:130 2014-05-14:130 2014-05-15:130 2014-05-16:130 2014-05-17:130 2014-05-18:130 2014-05-19:130 2014-05-20:130 2014-05-21:130 2014-05-22:130 2014-05-23:130 2014-05-24:130 2014-05-25:130 2014-05-26:130 2014-05-27:130 2014-05-28:130 2014-05-29:130 2014-05-30:130 2014-05-31:130 2014-06-01:130 2014-06-02:130 2014-06-03:130 2014-06-04:130 2014-06-05:130 2014-06-06:130 2014-06-07:130 2014-06-08:130 2014-06-09:130 2014-06-10:130 2014-06-11:130 2014-06-12:130 2014-06-13:130 2014-06-14:130 2014-06-15:130 2014-06-16:130 2014-06-17:130 2014-06-18:130 2014-06-19:130 2014-06-20:130 2014-06-21:130 2014-06-22:130 2014-06-23:130 2014-06-24:130 2014-06-25:130 2014-06-26:130 2014-06-27:130 2014-06-28:130 2014-06-29:130 2014-06-30:130 2014-07-01:130 2014-07-02:130 2014-07-03:130 2014-07-04:130 2014-07-05:130 2014-07-06:130 2014-07-07:130 2014-07-08:130 2014-07-09:130 2014-07-10:130 2014-07-11:130 2014-07-12:130 2014-07-13:130 2014-07-14:130 2014-07-15:130 2014-07-16:130 2014-07-17:130 2014-07-18:130 2014-07-19:170 2014-07-20:170 2014-07-21:170 2014-07-22:170 2014-07-23:170 2014-07-24:170 2014-07-25:170 2014-07-26:170 2014-07-27:170 2014-07-28:170 2014-07-29:170 2014-07-30:170 2014-07-31:170 2014-08-01:170 2014-08-02:170 2014-08-03:170 2014-08-04:170 2014-08-05:170 2014-08-06:170 2014-08-07:170 2014-08-08:170 2014-08-09:170 2014-08-10:170 2014-08-11:170 2014-08-12:170 2014-08-13:170 2014-08-14:170 2014-08-15:170 2014-08-16:170 2014-08-17:170 2014-08-18:170 2014-08-19:170 2014-08-20:170 2014-08-21:170 2014-08-22:170 2014-08-23:170 2014-08-24:170 2014-08-25:170 2014-08-26:170 2014-08-27:170 2014-08-28:170 2014-08-29:170 2014-08-30:170
</str>
```

As you can see the structure of the string is date:price.

Basically, I would like to parse the string to get the price for a particular period and sort by that price.
I’ve already developed the java plugin for the custom function query and I’m at the point where my code compiles, runs, executes, etc. Solr is happy with my code.

Example:

```
price(daily_prices_str,2015-01-01,2015-01-03)
```

If I run this query I can see the correct price in the score field:

```
/select?price=price(daily_prices_str,2015-01-01,2015-01-03)&q={!func}$price
```

One of the problems is that I cannot sort by function result.
If I run this query:

```
/select?price=price(daily_prices_str,2015-01-01,2015-01-03)&q={!func}$price&sort=$price+asc
```

I get a 404 saying that "*sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: $price*"
But it works with a workaround:

```
/select?price=sum(0,price(daily_prices_str,2015-01-01,2015-01-03))&q={!func}$price&sort=$price+asc
```

The main problem is that I cannot filter by range:

```
/select?price=sum(0,price(daily_prices_str,2015-1-1,2015-1-3))&q={!frange l=100 u=400}$price
```

Maybe I'm going about this totally incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the newly created "price" to the "sort" parameter, can you pass the function with data itself like so?

```
q=*:*&sort=price(daily_prices_str,2015-01-01,2015-01-03) ...
```

Comment: I already tried and it didn't work, the only way I found to don't get any error is to "wrap" my function inside the sum function.